# How to render component as soon as the value stored in local in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-component

I want to show one component only if a value ('id') is stored in the localStorage. And id is stored when the button is clicked.

```
{localStorage.getItem('id') != null ? <Game/> : null }
```

It works fine, so I click the button and store the id in localStorage but only after I refresh I am able to see  component. But I want to render the component as soon as it is stored in local (refresh the page shouldnt be needed)

Any suggest to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My version, with custom hook.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState,useEffect } from "react";

function useLocalStorage(key) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(localStorage.getItem(key));
  function setStorage(item) {
    localStorage.setItem(key, item);
    setState(item);
  }
  return [state, setStorage];
}

export default function App() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [item, setItem] = useLocalStorage("myKey");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input value={input} onInput={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={() => setItem(input)}>Click</button>
      <p>{item}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-sea-d6ni42?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

components usually render with the state change. you can bind one state for local storage (if u need local storage anyway) and just update the state each time.
if you want to store in local storage then take value from the state.

example:

```
const [userid, setUserId] = useState(localStorage.getItem('id'));


const onSave : (value) => {
   localStorage.setItem('id', JSON.stringify(value))
   setUserId(value)
}

return (
    <div>
       {userid != null ? <Game/> : null }
    </div>
)
```

Comment: Can you give me an example, I can understand better I think

Answer (score 1):

You have to use state management, the local storage has updated but your DOM is unaware of it, to fix this check the following example

for this we use the useState hook, here we initialize the idLocal value with the value from local storage

```
  let [idLocal, setIdLocal] = useState(localStorage.getItem("id"));
```

then you have to use this value for the condition as changes to this value will be visible in DOM , the `setIdLocal` is used to set or update this `idLocal`

```
{idLocal? <Game/> : null }
```

for updating the value on the button click

```
 <button onClick={()=>setLocalstore()}>Off</button>

setLocalstore =()=>{
setIdLocal(whatever value you want)
}
```

check out this minimal example https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-usestate-forked-5j6ck0?file=/src/index.js:567-605

Answer (score 1):

**1.Initiate state:**

```js
const [id, setId] = useState(
  localStorage.getItem('id') ? <Game/> : null
);
```

**2.Save every change inside local storage:**

```js
useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem('id', id);
}, [id])
```

**3.Render component using state**